# I want to customize DataSource for solr that define one time dataSource and use for multiple core

Tags: solr

For Every Solr core to connect with database i need to define datasource connection in data-config.xml and delta-data-config.xml.
I want to just want to define datasource one time like acquire value from the another location or just define datasource one time and use it in multiple solr core in data-config.xml or  delta-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
   <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"driver=${driver}url=${url}user=${username}password=${password}/>
   <document>
      <entity name="name"  query="sql Query"></entity>
   </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Specify your question please!

Comment: @dmytro-dadyka


For Every data-config.xml or delta-data-config.xml i need to define <dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver=driver
              url="url"              user="username"
              password="password"
    />
  <document>

instead of that i want use only one Global dataource  .that  i have to not define in evry data-config.xml or delta-data-config.xml.

Comment: did you get it now ????

Comment: Please, add this to your question. Use "edit".

Comment: @DmytroDadyka i have edited Question . Let me if yet has need to change